# Are all img supposed to be 100% with basic Bootstrap setup?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I'm creating a site using `bootstrap 3.0.3` and implemented the bootstrap carousel in the header.

I had been pounding away at the page for days which had appeared to be working properly without issue and then I noticed something unusual. All of the images on the page were at one point at a 100%.

I hadn't placed them on a grid and so that seemed to me to be normal/default behavior. Now they are all displaying at their precise dimensions. This of course is affecting my Hero/Carousel images when my browser is fully expanded as they are now displaying with some grey space to the right, however, they do resize and fill the page as I reduce the size of my window.

I've trouble shot this issue by downloading a fresh copy of bootstrap and creating a new html file (code supplied below) then adding the carousel template code from the bootstrap website in and placing the images I was using. After doing so, the images are still not bleeding to the edges when my browser is open to it's maximum width.

I've never had this issue before with bootstrap or the carousel and so I'm completely stumped. Is the default width of `img` not 100% because it sure looked like it was in the `bootstrap.css` file. Additionally I've added `img width:100% !important` to the `head` of my document and everything returned to the way it was before this issue occurred.

I'm wondering if this is just a change that was made recently and when I updated bootstrap it changed everything? And if so, is the carousel not supposed to stretch the image to the edges?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Carousel -->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/hero-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/hero-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/hero-3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </div>
        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the applied css attributes for the parents which contain img?  Maybe something has a different width attribute?

Comment: I went through and check attributes on the div body selectors and found no conflicting size attributes. I've used BS 2.3 and my carousel images display responsively without having to supply larger images. Now with 3.0.3 it appears to be stretching responsively until it reaches the length of image (1578px). The code I'm working on is just an overhaul of a site I built using bootstrap 2.3.0. That site exists live on the web and is working with the exact same images. I even took the code from my existing site and used it with the updated version of bootstrap and it is exhibiting this issue.

Comment: Also to note, I've discovered that 3.0.3 did away with responsive css and now has a class for img-reponsive. I applied this in my test code above and it fixed the issue. I applied it to my main file and the issue still persists. :(

Comment: Scratch that last note. I had a width set to 100%. It did not fix my issue. Double :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BS3 implements responsive images differently than they did in BS2. Images that are to behave responsively are assigned a class of **.img-responsive** to the **img** element. For some reason, the people at Twitter think this was a good idea, but I can't figure out why.

Unfortunately, this tends to be too much work and defeats the purpose of using the responsive framework. With every BS3 project, I simply add...

```
img { max-width:100%; height:auto; }
```

... at the top my stylesheet. This makes all images fill their containers up to their native resolution. So, if the image width is less than the container width it's in, it will not be sized beyond its original dimensions.

Hope this helps.